# Using Bootstrap Modal to display View with MVC5/razor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I have a Users list view that contains a foreach to display users.

**Username is made clickable with this:**

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.UserName, "UserSetAccess", new { id=item.Id }, new{ @class = "dialog" } )
```

**The rendered HTML:**

```
<a href="/Admin/UserSetAccess/37ebbad8-c952-4a75-91d2-197d78d1b175" class="dialog">testCustomer7@example.com</a>
```

**Clicking the link triggers this jQuery:**

```
$(function () {
    $('a.dialog').click(function () {
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        var dialog = $('<div style="display:none"></div>').appendTo('body');
        dialog.load(url, {},
            function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                dialog.dialog({
                    close: function (event, ui) {
                        dialog.remove();
                    }
                });
            });
        return false;
    });
});
```

There are no `<form>` tags on this page, yet I have set a breakpoint on both the GET and POST UserSetAccess Actions in the controller and the only one that gets hit is the POST which messes up the dialog.

Why is .load() issuing a POST instead of GET? The dialog should initially popup and contain the View from a GET and then allow changes so I can submit them and do a POST.

Does anyone see a problem with the above code or have an alternative way of making this work correctly? I've researched .load() and don't see anyplace that says it issues a POST.

**EDIT**

By request, I am including the Controller Action methods. Both of these are pretty much default. I commented out the ValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute on the POST Action because it was erroring out - probably part of the same issue as my question. I'll figure out that problem later.

GET Controller Action:

```
    //
    // GET: /Admin/UserSetAccess/1
    public async Task<ActionResult> UserSetAccess(string id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        var userRoles = await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user.Id);

        return View(new UserProfileViewModel()
        {
            Id = user.Id,
            Email = user.Email,
            IsApproved = user.IsApproved,
            Name = user.Name,
            Company = user.Company,

            RolesList = RoleManager.Roles.ToList().Select(x => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Selected = userRoles.Contains(x.Name),
                Text = x.Name,
                Value = x.Name
            })
        });
    }
```

POST Controller Action:

```
    //
    // POST: /Admin/UserSetAccess/5
    [HttpPost]
    //[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> UserSetAccess([Bind(Include = "Email,Id,IsApproved,Name,Company")] 
        UserProfileViewModel editUser, params string[] selectedRole)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(editUser.Id);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            user.UserName = editUser.Email;
            user.Email = editUser.Email;
            user.IsApproved = editUser.IsApproved;
            user.Name = editUser.Name;
            user.Company = editUser.Company;

            var userRoles = await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user.Id);

            selectedRole = selectedRole ?? new string[] { };

            var result = await UserManager.AddToRolesAsync(user.Id, selectedRole.Except(userRoles).ToArray<string>());

            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", result.Errors.First());
                return View();
            }
            result = await UserManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync(user.Id, userRoles.Except(selectedRole).ToArray<string>());

            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", result.Errors.First());
                return View();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Users");
        }
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Something failed.");
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Could you post your two server side methods (both the GET and POST) including any attributes on them or the classes.

Comment: Justin, I edited the question and included both Controller Actions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the `POST` is happening is because you're passing an object to the `.load()` method.  From the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

> The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise,
>   GET is assumed.

Your code should just look like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('a.dialog').click(function () {
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        var dialog = $('<div style="display:none"></div>').appendTo('body');
        dialog.load(url,
            function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                dialog.dialog({
                    close: function (event, ui) {
                        dialog.remove();
                    }
                });
            });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Notice that I omitted the `{}` in the call to `.load()`.